# What does "mainstream pop music" mean? And does it consist of a single main categorisation or multiple ones?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-usage

Is "mainstream pop music" just *a genre* or *genres*?

Whatever it means, can I use it as below?

> What kind of mainstream pop music do you like?
>   What kinds of mainstream pop music do you like?

Comment: The question 'What does _mainstream_ mean' is clearly off-topic here as general reference. But the actual implications of the way the word is used within a given domain or sub-domain (pop music) are really more domain-related than general-English related.

Comment: In fact ODO actually references music in its entry for [mainstream](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mainstream). However, whether *music* can be split into *kinds* or remains as *kind* is probably a valid question if it hasn't been asked before.

Comment: Technically, "pop" is short for "popular", and "mainstream" means, roughly, "the most common".  So the term is (taken literally) kind of redundant.  However, "pop" has come to mean a particular (rather broad and ill-defined) genre (that usually is assumed to exclude most "country" music, eg, even though country is, alas, quite popular).  So it's quite confusing.

Comment: Science fiction is a genre, but it's reasonable to ask "what kinds of science fiction do you like?" The question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

There is not one universally agreed upon taxonomy of musical genres (though there have been efforts to create one). Most taxonomies recognize that musical genres can be classified in a hierarchical system. For example, the digital music store at Amazon.com has a top level genre (or "root genre") called Pop, and within that there are eleven sub-genres, including Dance Pop, Soft Pop, Euro Pop, Pop Rock, and Adult Alternative.

"Mainstream Pop Music" probably equates to Pop Rock, by Amazon's taxonomy.

To answer your question, **music** is a **mass noun**. Unlike count nouns, mass nouns have no plural form and cannot by used with numbers.

And yes, you can use either **kind** or **kinds** with **music**.

But here is another possible way to formulate your sentence:

> What sub-genres of Pop Music do you like?

Comment: There's also plenty of overlap between genres. There's crossover between Country and Pop, so someone might answer that their favorite type of pop music is country.

Answer (score 0):

My view as a music producer.

Mainstream pop music is the default. In other words what the current mass media outlets are pushing. They are pushing this because the major labels are pushing it.

So if someone says they listen to mainstream pop, then they are not really a music fan, just happy to receive what is being pushed to them.

It is several genres.

I would choose..
What kinds of mainstream pop music do you like?

Or..
"What sort of pop music do you like?" will suffice because pop is mainstream anyway ( pop as in popular )